# Aligning lines in text file

Tags: linux, file, text, formatting, alignment

I have data in the text file as below

```
E993143|65282
C960954567|50222
P1_ABCDEFG_bbb|26153
A960416|25654
D987747|13410
```

I would like to have in a proper alignment using linux as below

```
E993143                  |65282
C960954567               |50222
P1_ABCDEFG_bbb           |26153
A960416                  |25654
D987747                  |13410
```

Can somebody help me here?
Note: I cannot use excel format

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk as follows over your text:

```
awk -F"|" '{printf("%-15s \t |%-10i\n", $1, $2)}'
```

In this, I have fixed the max-length for 1st column as '15' and second as '10'. You can change these numbers if you are expecting a larger length.

Explanation:

- "-F" flag defines the delimiter as "|"
- "%-15s \t |%-10i\n" - this section is defining how we want the output string to be formatted. ' - ' in '-15s' is for left alignment of the output column and '15s' is for 15 character length string. Similarly '-10i' is for 10 digit integer value. "\t" and "\n" is to add tab space in between and line space at the end.

Output:

```
➜  test cat test.txt | awk -F"|" '{printf("%-15s \t |%-10i\n", $1, $2)}'
E993143                  |65282     
C960954567               |50222     
P1_ABCDEFG_bbb           |26153     
A960416                  |25654     
D987747                  |13410     
➜  test
```

Answer (score 0):

the tool "column" might help you : https://www.stefaanlippens.net/pretty-csv.html. like

```
cat test.csv | column -t -s \| -o \|
```

"|" needs escaping when used as parameter-input